# How to filter out c-type comments with regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to filter out "c-style" comments in a line so i'm only left with the words (or actual code).

This is what i have so far: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kfRgNQ/3)

regex:

```
\/\*[^\/]*[^\*]*\*\/
```

text:

```
/* 1111 */ one /*2222*/two /*3333 */ three/* 4444*/ four /*/**/ five /**/
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

This matches any old-school C style comment.  It works by using a *lazy* dot `.*?` to match only content within a single comment, before the end of that comment.  We can then replace with empty string, to effectively remove these comments from the input.

Code:

```
Dim input As String = "/* 1111 */ one /*2222*/two /*3333 */ three/* 4444*/ four /*/**/ five /**/"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "/\*.*?\*/", "")
Console.WriteLine(input)
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

This prints:

```
one two  three four  five
```

Comment: Perfect! so that was the deal with "?". I was not very sure how to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might likely work,

```
\/\*(\/\*\*\/)?\s*([^\/*]+?)\s*(?:\/?\*?\*?\/|\*)
```

or we would modify our left and right boundaries, if we would have had different inputs.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8O7kO0/1), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.